# How can we define an usable coordinate system for quantum systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, coordinate-systems, quantum-interpretations

As A. Einstein wrote in his introductory book on special relativity (translated from the Portuguese version):

> Any spacial description of the localization of any event or object is based on the specification of a point from a rigid-body (reference body or referential) which coincides with such event.

This is the usual treatment for space when we study classical physics or relativity, we can only think of it when occupied by something. And coordinates will be simple numbers indicating positions on rigid bodies.

Now when go to quantum mechanics, we describe equations and functions defined on coordinate systems, without assuring their existence.
Won't any physical body at the quantum scale exhibit vibrations, making them impossible to be used as a ruler?
Regarding to this, I wonder how can we talk e.g. of the density of probability of a particle in a given position $x$, if we can't define the position $x$ precisely at such small scales? Isn't this "impossibility of having a perfect ruler at quantum scales" the reason of the quantum uncertainty? In a way that instead of the particle being spread out or not localized, it is the ruler that is uncertain and vibrating.

Comment: I don't think the rulers are as uncertain as you claim: see e.g. [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanoruler).

Answer (score 1):

In principle a ruler does have an uncertainty in its length, but that doesn't mean we can't measure its length precisely. (Note that in practice macroscopic objects don't have a position uncertainty due to a process called *decoherence*, but we can skip over this for now.)

Suppose we have a 1m ruler and we measure its length, then we'll get some result $1 + \varepsilon$ metres where $\varepsilon$ is the difference from a metre due to the uncertainty principle. Now we measure it a second time and we get a different length $1 + \varepsilon_2$, then measure it a third time and we get $1 + \varepsilon_3$, and so on. Now we plot a histogram of all our length measurements and we will get a curve something like this:

[image: Length]

The peak of our curve is at a length of 1m and the width of the curve is the position uncertainty $\Delta x$. And we can measure the peak position as accurately as we want just by doing many measurements to define the curve precisely. So the uncertainty principle doesn't prevent us using our ruler precisely, it just means we may have to make lots of measurements and average them to get a precise result.

More precisely, even when there is an uncertainty in position the [expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_value_(quantum_mechanics)) of position can still be defined precisely.

For macroscopic objects the quantum uncertainty is negligible and in practice we are limited by experimental errors that have nothing to do with quantum mechanics, and of course making many measurements and averaging them is exactly how we reduce the experimental error.